# Imageview not showing unless rotate or resume

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, imageview

I am working on my movie project which fetch movie poster from URL, and then putting them into a gridview. I use asynctask to fetch JSON and the parse the url within the json file. However, when I launch my app, the grid is all empty and doing nothing until I rotate my screen or resume my app. Once I rotate my screen or resume my app. It shows all picture. I remove my api key on my code here.

```
public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String api_key = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String movieJsonStr = null;

        try {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .authority("api.themoviedb.org")
                    .appendPath("3")
                    .appendPath("discover")
                    .appendPath("movie")
                    .appendQueryParameter("api_key", api_key);
            String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

            URL Url = new URL(myUrl);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, myUrl);
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                movieJsonStr = null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                movieJsonStr = null;
            }

            movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            Log.v("KPN", movieJsonStr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
            // to parse it.
            movieJsonStr = null;
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }

            }
        }
        try {
            MovieURL = getPosterUrlFromJson(movieJsonStr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> getPosterUrlFromJson(String forcastMovieStr)
        throws JSONException {

    final String OWM_PosterUrl = "poster_path";
    final String OWM_releaseDate = "release_date";
    final String OWM_overview = "overview";
    final String OWM_vote_average = "vote_average";
    final String OWM_original_title = "original_title";
    final String OWM_results = "results";


    JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forcastMovieStr);
    JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(OWM_results);

    ArrayList<String> resultStrs = new ArrayList<>();
    String posterurl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";

    for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
        // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
        String title;
        String overview;
        String poster;

        // Get the JSON object for movie poster
        JSONObject moveposter = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
        poster = moveposter.getString(OWM_PosterUrl);

        resultStrs.add(i,posterurl + poster);

    }
    return resultStrs;
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    MovieURL.clear();
    for (String s : strings) {
        MovieURL.add(s);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<String> MovieURL = new ArrayList();
public static ImageListAdapter mImageListAdapter;
public GridView gridview;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new FetchMovieTask().execute();
    mImageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(this,MovieURL);
    gridview.setAdapter(mImageListAdapter);
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);


}

private void updateMovieURL(){
    new FetchMovieTask().execute();
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}
```

ImagelistAdapter class

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <String> imageUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.image_view, imageUrls);

    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, parent, false);
    }

    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrls.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .into((ImageView) convertView);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

THanks guys

Answer (score 0):

In postExecute do this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    MovieURL.clear();
    for (String s : strings) {
        MovieURL.add(s);
    }
mImageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem on the asynctask, I didnt override the onPostExecute method. After I override my onPostExecute, I initial my grid view

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        mImageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this, MovieURL);
        gridview.setAdapter(mImageListAdapter);
    }
```